# input type file with file path

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I want to import data from a path in an input type file.

It is in use in the kendo UI, and when I wrote the article, I uploaded the data to the spreadsheet by using the file upload window and saved the data to the server.

Therefore, the file is stored in the server-specified path, and DB contains basic information such as file path, file name, and extension.

When I read a post using this, it was successful to retrieve the information of the file from the DB, but it is not in the reading part of the file.

So, I do not upload the file from the input type file that I used at the time of writing, but I want to read the file information from fromfile.

If you know how to do it, please let me know.

This is the code I used to write.

```
<input class="icon_input_file" type="file" id="insertFile" name="insertFile"/>

$("#insertFile").on("change", function(){
    var spreadsheet = $("#spreadsheet").data("kendoSpreadsheet");
    spreadsheet.fromFile(this.files[0]);
});
```

Comment: I have tested the scenario in [this dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aZosuH) and it worked correctly at my side. Here is a [video](https://www.screencast.com/t/EJz2tSMFutz) of my test. Would you please elaborate what is difference at your side?

Comment: @Plamen Zdravkov I would like to import it using the file path, not the file upload window.   I would like to have the source code above used in writing and to replace the above source code with only the file path